# How to Change Magento admin panel menu position?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, sort

I have created custom extension.

But in admin panel it is display as a main menu on backend of magento, and i need to show it in `system->configuration section`.

Go to following link i have upload screenshot of admin panel.

[go to link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p86mX.jpg)

Following is my adminhtml.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
<menu>
    <BrandInfo module="bcall">
        <title>BrandInfo</title>
        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
    </BrandInfo>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <bcall>
                                    <title>BrandInfo</title>
                                </bcall>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

My system.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
<tabs>
    <BrandInfo translate="label" module="bcall">
        <label>BrandInfo</label>
        <sort_order>250</sort_order>
    </BrandInfo>
</tabs>
</config>
```

for manage manufacturer subtab adminhtml.xml file is,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<menu>
    <BrandInfo module="manufacturer">
        <children>
            <logo module="manufacturer">
                <title>Manage Manufacturer</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>manufacturer/adminhtml_manufacturer</action>
            </logo>
        </children>
    </BrandInfo>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <BrandInfo>
                    <title>BrandInfo</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <logo module="manufacturer" translate="title">
                            <title>Manage Manufacturer</title>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                     <action>manufacturer/adminhtml_manufacturer</action>
                        </logo>
                    </children>
                </BrandInfo>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
<layout>
    <updates>
        <manufacturer>
            <file>manufacturer.xml</file>
        </manufacturer>
    </updates>
</layout>

</config>
```

For "Manage Manufacturer"  adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
<menu>
    <BrandInfo module="manufacturer">
        <children>
            <logo module="manufacturer">
                <title>Manage Manufacturer</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>manufacturer/adminhtml_manufacturer</action>
            </logo>
        </children>
    </BrandInfo>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <BrandInfo>
                    <title>BrandInfo</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <logo module="manufacturer" translate="title">
                            <title>Manage Manufacturer</title>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <action>manufacturer/adminhtml_manufacturer</action>
                        </logo>
                    </children>
                </BrandInfo>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
<layout>
    <updates>
        <manufacturer>
            <file>manufacturer.xml</file>
        </manufacturer>
    </updates>
</layout>

</config>
```

i am new in magento so please Anybody knows answer please share. your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you create system.xml file to create tab in configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<config>    
<menu>
 <marketplace>
        <title>Marketplace< /title>  
        <sort_order>80< /sort_order>   
     <children>  
            <chat module="chat" translate="title">  
                <title>Chat< / title>  
                <sort_order>70< /sort_order>   
                <action>adminhtml/chat/chatclient< /action>  
            </chat>  
    </children>  
  </marketplace>        
</menu>

<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all> 
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <magecomp_chat>
                                    <title>chat</title>
                                </magecomp_chat>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
                <marketplace module="marketplace" translate="title">
                    <children>
                        <chat module="chat" translate="title">
                            <title>Chat</title>
                            <sort_order>70</sort_order> 
                            <action>adminhtml/chat/chatclient</action>
                        </chat>
                    </children>
                </marketplace>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

system.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
<tabs>
    <BrandInfo translate="label" module="bcall">
        <label>BrandInfo</label>
        <sort_order>250</sort_order>
    </BrandInfo>
</tabs>
    <sections>
        <bradninfo translate="label" module="bcall">
            <label>Bradninfo</label>
            <tab>BrandInfo</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <groups>
                <general translate="label">
                    <label>General Configuration</label>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <fields>
                        <activation translate="label">
                            <label>Vendor System</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <comment></comment>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_enabledisable</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        </activation>
                    </fields>
                </general>
            </groups>
        </bradninfo>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: i have update my question see system.xml file.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<config>  
 <sections>  
  <vimportexport translate="label" module="vimportexport">  
   <label>Import Export</label>  
   <tab>general</tab>  
   <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>  
   <sort_order>110</sort_order>  
   <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>  
   <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>  
   
  </vimportexport>  
 </sections>  
</config>

Comment: you code like this in your system.xml to creata tab

Comment: my BrandInfo tab have subtab like "manage manufacturer" after clicking on manage manufacturer link is open an manage manufacturer tab code in another manage adminhtml.xml file. see  adminhtml.xml file in updated question.

Comment: i update my answer you just check

Comment: you change sort order of menu to change its position.

Comment: can you update this code in my system.xml file?

Comment: because my system.xml file and your code totally diffrent

Comment: i am new in magento please update my system.xml file.

Comment: system.xml file and adminhtml.xml file totly diffrent. its depend on you that what you add in configuration. that code you define in system.xml file

Comment: you check i update system.xml

Comment: it showing my extension in system->configuration but after clicking on brandinfo it showing 404 error

Comment: delete cache and session in var folder and re-login

Comment: kindly note that my BrandInfo  tab having "Manage manufacture" subtab and its adminhtml.xml file  is i have updated in question.

Comment: i have delete everything but still showing 404 error

Comment: can you give sreenshot ? so i can understand what you exactly want

Comment: please  help me.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/cHhDl  go to this link and see first image of brandInfo tab. after mousehover on this brandInfo tab having subtab  "manage manufacturer" and after clicking if "manage manufacturer" it showing all extension output.

Comment: please suggest me something

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/  follow this

Answer (score 0):

Open adminhtml.xml file of your extension and find sort_order tag in this
fiel and mention sorting value as below.
Numerical value

Each menu item has a sort order. For top level menu items, lower numbers
will sort further to the left, higher numbers to the right. For sub-menu
items the sort is top/down.